# Loop through Objects, duplicate show only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

```
 var fixtures = [
        {
          "matchday": 1,
            "homeTeamName": "Arsenal FC",
            "awayTeamName": "Leicester City FC"
          },
           {
          "matchday": 1,
              "homeTeamName": "AFC Bournemouth",
              "awayTeamName": "Watford FC",
          },
            {


            "matchday": 1,
                "homeTeamName": "Burnley FC",
                  "awayTeamName": "West Bromwich Albion FC",
              },
               {
              "matchday": 1,
                "homeTeamName": "Leicester City FC",
                  "awayTeamName": "Brighton & Hove Albion",
              },
             {
               "matchday": 2,
                  "homeTeamName": "Liverpool FC",
                  "awayTeamName": "Crystal Palace FC",
              },
               {
               "matchday": 2,
                  "homeTeamName": "Stoke City FC",
                  "awayTeamName": "Arsenal FC",
              },

            ];
```

I have this code and I want to show all the teams with the same matchday in an adjacent rows, meaning match day will show on the first row followed by teams that playing on that day.

[image]

I've tried this

```
var x = '';

for(var key in fixtures){
                x += '<tr><th colspan="2">Match Day: ' + fixtures[key].matchday + '</th></tr>'+
                '<tr><td>' + fixtures[key].homeTeamName + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + fixtures[key].awayTeamName + '<td></tr>';

            }


$("#test").html(x);
```

but got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIylq.png)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service

Comment: Okay, check my edited version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, this will only ad a "match day" when its a new one.

```
var mday = 0;
for (var key in fixtures) {
  if (mday != fixtures[key].matchday) {
    mday = fixtures[key].matchday
    x += '<tr><th colspan="2">Match Day: ' + fixtures[key].matchday + '</th></tr>';
  }

  x += '<tr><td>' + fixtures[key].homeTeamName + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + fixtures[key].awayTeamName + '<td></tr>';

}
```

**Demo**

```js
var fixtures = [{
    "matchday": 1,
    "homeTeamName": "Arsenal FC",
    "awayTeamName": "Leicester City FC"
  },
  {
    "matchday": 1,
    "homeTeamName": "AFC Bournemouth",
    "awayTeamName": "Watford FC",
  },
  {


    "matchday": 1,
    "homeTeamName": "Burnley FC",
    "awayTeamName": "West Bromwich Albion FC",
  },
  {
    "matchday": 1,
    "homeTeamName": "Leicester City FC",
    "awayTeamName": "Brighton & Hove Albion",
  },
  {
    "matchday": 2,
    "homeTeamName": "Liverpool FC",
    "awayTeamName": "Crystal Palace FC",
  },
  {
    "matchday": 2,
    "homeTeamName": "Stoke City FC",
    "awayTeamName": "Arsenal FC",
  },

];

var x = '';
var mday = 0;

for (var key in fixtures) {
  if (mday != fixtures[key].matchday) {
    mday = fixtures[key].matchday
    x += '<tr><th colspan="2">Match Day: ' + fixtures[key].matchday + '</th></tr>';
  }

  x += '<tr><td>' + fixtures[key].homeTeamName + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + fixtures[key].awayTeamName + '<td></tr>';

}


$("#test").html(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks a million.

Comment: @Ahmed No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

if your array is sorted by matchday(it must be sorted) you may remember previous item's matchday and compare it to current one. Once it's different - you're putting closing tags for previous section and starting new one.